# Timeline "spike" similarity metric?

Tags: binary-data, similarities, timelines

Imagine you have a single axis. Along the axis are placed several target points, at differing distances between each other.

You now have a black box that shoots a variable number of points on to the axis, with the goal of hitting as close as possible, with the minimal number of shots. The number of shots is not determined in advance, the black box that is shooting them will do that.

What we want to do is measure which of N such black boxes is the most accurate and more importantly, how accurate it is relative to another black box.

From the target POV, we can divide the axis into equal spaced bisections between the targets, and can therefor sum the error of the shots that land within those boundaries for each target as the distance to the closest target.

However, this doesn't account for the case where we shoot 2 bullets at 2 targets, but both bullets hit the same target. In this case, we'd get a 100% accuracy over two bullets, even though one of them (ideally) should have hit the other target. So clearly we need some notion of "recall" (how many targets were hit), *but*, now consider the other version of this, in which an adversary gives 100 targets and yet we hit say 10 of those equally spaced targets with 10 bullets.

To me this has the feeling of some kind of clustering algorithm, but in reverse. I don't know if I can reverse a k-Means or something like it.

The actual use case is in comparing timelines that have discrete events, and I want to know which of a target timeline is most like another one (and by how much).

So my question is, what would be the correct metric?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In particular, neither the Title nor the Body contain a question mark. It's very difficult to answer a non-existent question.

Comment: ah I apologize.

Comment: I believe I've found something "close enough"  in the Music Information Retrieval world - https://craffel.github.io/mir_eval/#mir_eval.segment.deviation although, I modified it to use the sum of the deviations rather than the median.